# Trigger on Child record to update Parent Record and to create new Child records ( same )

Tags: trigger, design-patterns, pattern

I have been trying to come up with the pattern in which i need to handle the below scenario ( considering recursion ).

On Insertion of Child Record ( Object - B ) i need to update parent record ( object - A) as well as conditionally insert object ( object - B again ).

Could anyone point me what is the best way to handle this kind of scenario?

** EDIT **

Sorry if its confusing. Giving another shot :)

Initially Insert record for Object B ( consider of type Apple ) , after that update Object A and then based on some criteria create new records for Object B ( this time it might be Mango and Orange ) again after that need to update Object A .

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by inserting a record that was just inserted? Do you mean update?

Comment: In addition to Eric's comment, have you tried to create this using Process Builder instead? https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BHvJIAW. You may be able to achieve what you want to do via Process Builder instead of code.

Comment: At what point do you stop updating object a and creating new object b. I am afraid your question is way to broad as it is. Only answer we could give is to read up on how to write triggers and insert records